# openness in subset is equivalent to openness in the mother space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

My question is 25.b from textbook real mathematical analysis, and it says
[image]

What I am thinking about is that there is a $V$ open in $M$, s.t. $S$ is the intersection of $V$ and $N$ ($V$ is open in $M$), which means $S$ is open in $N$. But I do not know how to follow the condition that $S$ is also open in $M$ to show $N$ is also open.

I have tried to use contra-positive, but it gives no useful results. (i.e. if we are given that $N$ is not open in $M$, I want to prove open in $N$ does not imply open in $M$. $S$ is the intersection of $V$ and $N$ as above. But I just can not exclude the situation when $S$ is open in $M$, $S$ intersecting $N$, which is $N$, will always be open in $N$. )

So what is the correct way to prove this? Thx!

Comment: I think you're on the right track with the contrapositive. Suppose $N$ is not open in $M$. What can you say about the set $S = N$?

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that what if S=N, and S is open in N, with N not open in M?

Comment: Right, suppose that $N$ is not open in $M$. The goal is to show that openness of $S \subset N$ is *not* equivalent to openness of $S \subset M$. To do this, it suffices to find any set $S \subset N$ which is open in $N$ but not in $M$. The set $S=N$ is one such set, because $N$ is open in itself but not in $M$.